# Make UITabBar wait for user input before switching tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have a `UITabBar` with 5 tabs. When the middle tab is selected I want a `UIAlertController` Action Sheet to pop up, await user action and then load the new view once the user has selected from the Sheet since I need the data from the Sheet to load the view correctly.

I currently have this code:

```
extension CustomTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let index = viewControllers?.index(of: viewController) else {
            return false
        }
        if index == 2 {
            var choice = CreateChoice()

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Creation Type", message: "Please select the desired creation type", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Quick Create", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                choice.choice = "quick"
            }

            let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                choice.choice = "cancel"
            }

            let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Full Create", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                choice.choice = "full"
            }

            alert.addAction(action1)
            alert.addAction(action2)
            alert.addAction(action3)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print(choice.choice)
            if choice.choice == "cancel" {
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

This works in every way except the new view loads before the user selects anything from the Action Sheet. Is it possible to make the `UITabBar` wait for the action or do I need to go about this another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to always return `false` in the delegate and **programatically** change to the required index in case the user taps the required action in the alert.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let index = viewControllers?.index(of: viewController) else {
        return false
    }
    if index == 2 {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Creation Type", message: "Please select the desired creation type", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Quick Create", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
        }

        let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            // Do nothing
        }

        let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Full Create", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
        }

        alert.addAction(action1)
        alert.addAction(action2)
        alert.addAction(action3)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Btw you can avoid the choice variable if this works.

Comment: This worked great, thank you. Your code is just missing `return true` before the last brace close