# How to intercept tab bar selection?

Tags: ios, swift

If users touch any tab bar items, an alert is needed to present to confirm users' real intention.

Users can press OK to proceed the tab transitioning, or Cancel to stay on where they were.

However, methods like

```
tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

or

```
tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

seem to be impossible to intercept tab transitioning.

Any solutions to work around such issue?

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278321/7734643 In you case you wouldn't have the `if` condition, instead you'll always show the alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement

```
UITabBarControllerDelegate
```

on your viewcontroller and there is a callback

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

So you can then deal with the changes.

Alternatively find out the current selected tab with

```
tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag
```